# How to compute confidence intervals for this impulse response?

Tags: r, var, confidence-interval, statistics-bootstrap

I am trying to create bootstrapped confidence intervals for my impulse responses. Basically, I need a confidence intervall for **each** impulse response observation of each variable. It's easier for me to show you with an example where I am stuck.

```
library(vars)
library(varexternalinstrument)
data(GKdata)

gkvar <- VAR(GKdata[, c("logip", "logcpi", "gs1", "ebp")], p = 12, type = "const")
shockcol <- externalinstrument(gkvar, GKdata$ff4_tc, "gs1")
shockcol

ma_representation <- Phi(gkvar, 50)
irfs <- apply(ma_representation, 3, function(x) x %*% shockcol) #unclear
irfs <- as.data.frame(t(irfs))
colnames(irfs) <- names(shockcol)
irfs
```

So far so good, we get the impulse responses for the 4 variables in the dataset. Now, for **each** observation in **each** variable I want to compute bootstrapped confidence intervals. Yet, I got stuck probably on the **statistics** to insert in the function. I indicated with a question mark below the missing code that I can't write

```
? <- function() # I need to create a function that says bootstrap for each observation of each variable, I don't know how to do it

boot <- boot(irfs, ?, R = 1000, stype = "w", sim = "ordinary")

boot_ci <- boot.ci(boot, conf = c(0.90, 0.95), type = c("norm", "basic", "perc", "bca"))
```

Can anyone help me with that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hey it's not an easy bootstrap to do. I am not familiar with what is in GKdata, but I suppose there is some time series information, from which you calculated the impulse etc. If you bootstrap, you need to sample your GKdata such that this information is preserved, which allows you to calculate the impulse sensibly

Comment: Ok let me phrase the question, can you simply sample with replacement from GKdata and calculate the impulse response etc ? If this is ok, then I can write the boot function

Comment: @StupidWolf thank you for your attention. Just to be clear, are you saying "instead of doing what I would like to do, just resampling from the original dataset and from there derive all I need"? If that's what you mean and I understood you correctly, yes, it works

Comment: @StupidWolf I think that you are very riight, your way may be the only feasible way I see

Comment: @StupidWolf It is important being a time series.  I am missing how it is computed CI when the external instrument approach is used. Can't it be that it is computed from the fitted value of the regression of the residual of the VAR on the instrument? The problem is that `externalinstrument`  doesn't show it. I could compute it though. Any thoughts?

Comment: If it is a linear regression most likely you can calculate the CI.. but if it's not, you might need to bootstrap. Bootstrap works if you know how to sample GKdata, from what I can see

Comment: @StupidWolf but then it messes up the ordering of the rows right? If that were not a problem, would you be able to write a code for it?

Comment: Ok i think i understand what the data is. From the reference, it is "monthly data on a variety of economic and financial variables over the period 1979:7 to 2012:6". So this means you sample the data in years. Hence the p=12 parameter

Comment: @StupidWolf exactly right, are you able to write a code for it? I can't unfortunately

Comment: You can see below, the bootstrap is more or less correct, what I am not sure of is why your c.i is so huge, maybe some outliers etc I dunno.. You are more familiar with this function than I am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the data is collected in a period from 1979:7 to 2012:6, hence every 12 rows is a year and the bootstrap should sample the year in a block.

We first add this information to the data:

```
Data = GKdata
Data$year = (1:nrow(Data) - 1) %/% 12
```

And we create a function, that takes in a list, with sampled indices, recombines them into a data.frame and performs the same fitting function. For boot, you cannot return a data.frame so we return a  matrix:

```
func = function(mylist,ind){

  mydf = do.call(rbind,mylist[ind])
  gkvar <- VAR(mydf[, c("logip", "logcpi", "gs1", "ebp")], p = 12, type = "const")
  shockcol <- externalinstrument(gkvar, mydf$ff4_tc, "gs1")

  ma_representation <- Phi(gkvar, 50)
  irfs <- t(apply(ma_representation, 3, function(x) x %*% shockcol)) #unclear
  colnames(irfs) <- names(shockcol)
  irfs
}
```

So we do the bootstrap by feeding it a list, that is split by the Year. The bootstrapping will sample the indices of this list, combine the sampled years into a new data frame and perform the fitting:

```
res = boot(split(Data,Data$year),func,100)
```

We can check whether the function is doing the right thing on the original observation:

```
table(res$t0 == irfs)
```

Your irfs has 51 x 4 values. If we look at the estimates inside boot results, this is flattened out:

```
dim(res$t)
[1] 100 204
```

To get back the 95% confidence interval for each value or variable, we do:

```
boot_est= sapply(1:ncol(res$t),function(i){
  boot.ci(res,index=i,type = "perc")$percent[4:5]
})
```

And then create the upper and lower bound by putting them back into a matrix:

```
lb = matrix(boot_est[1,],ncol=ncol(res$t0))
ub = matrix(boot_est[2,],ncol=ncol(res$t0))
```

You can plot lets say the first column of irfs, somehow the ci is really huge for the first few entries:

```
plot(irfs[,1],ylim=c(-8,8))
lines(ub[,1])
lines(lb[,1])
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! This looks really brilliant! Thanks a lot. I am puzzled as well by the magnitude of the ci at the start. I will think about it. Thanks a lot, I could have never ever done it on my own. Thanks

Comment: I understood why ci are so big. This is what it is written in a note on the paper: "we are using wild bootstrap that generates valid confidence bands under heteroskedasticity and strong instruments. The estimation errors related to the instrumental variable regression is incorporated in the reported confidence bands, because both stages of the estimation are included in the bootstrapping procedure. Thereby, we avoid any potential “generated regressor” problem." The problem is now: how do I get residuals if `externalinstrument` shows me only the instantaneous reponses?

Comment: from the quote I wrote, do you understand what sample they use to derive the ci? I thought it was the residual and, then, inferred that the reason why there are huge bands is that they use a different sample. My question remains: what are they bootstrapping?

Comment: oh i get your point now.. they are using a wild bootstrap, which I hope is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)#Wild_bootstrap. Ok if wiki is correct, it means you actually randomly weigh the residuals and re-fit

Comment: Then I need the residuals from `externainstrument`, right? It is not displayed, so I can regress VAR residuals on the instrument and wild-bootstrap these, in theory. Don't you agree?

Comment: Yes you are right. the residuals are here actually. gkvar$varresult contains all the linear models, so to get the residuals, you do gkvar$varresult$ebp$residuals

Comment: perfect! thanks, hopefully it won't be too difficult to write a code for wildbootstrapping those. I will rely on the code you wrote above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208763/discussion-between-stupidwolf-and-rollo99).

Comment: Texted you there